# jQuery Firefox issue on slideUp

Tags: jquery, firefox, height, slidedown, slideup

I have a simple function that hides a div tag with slide up. When I call the function, on Firefox the effect occurs normally, but the height of this div remains during the effect.

On Chrome and IE the height flows together with the animation, which is what supposed to happen.

The div has a defined height and the issue doesn't occur when I want to show the div with slide down.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and tell us what version of FF you're using?

Comment: add the following style `-moz-appearance:none; ` in your css.

Comment: I'm using the version 16 of Firefox. The -moz-appearance:none didn't work.